# EF6 Custom Connection String at login

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5.2

I have an MVC5 application utilizing the default ASP.Identity implementation.  I have customized the user to allow for all additional required data.  I am utilizing the UserName field following a firstname.lastname structure and have updated all to not use email address, as is the default set-up.  No problem to this point.  Now here's my challenge ...

I am trying to allow for a multi-tenant type structure, and as such, I need to require an additional field at log in, in this case, CompanyId, which is a user-defined int data field that is unique (capturing a state-issued license number so there is Zero likelihood of duplication), such that the userName (first) be tied to the CompanyId, allowing for the re-use of the username with various other Companies.

I need the CompanyId field to store the connectionString for the company and can then utilize the base implementation of asp.Identity.

I have searched until I'm blue in the face and have found a wealth of data about multi-tenancy, but nothing that seems to match my "simple?" use case.  I may be underthinking this, but it seems, at least outwardly, to not be that complicated, but I cannot figure out where to start.

```
public class CompanyConnection
    {
        public int CompanyId { get; set; }
        public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
    }
```

The default site configuration does not allow for registration but rather an application for account and on success an account is created so all post account creation business logic is identical, but user specific and really needs it's own database.  I know this could be handled via url requests with subdomains, but that creates a whole new set of challenges for me from SSL cert perspectives (all sites require EV certs) and don't really want to go down that road.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use CompanyConnection.ConnectionString instance. If your CompanyConneciton Class is static try the code below, otherwise get the ConnectionString from companyConnection object instance.

```
youDBContext conn = new yourDBContext();
conn.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = CompanyConnection.ConnectionString;
conn.Database.Connection.Open();
```